# autopopulate more than one fileds using relate field - SuiteCRM Version 7.10.4 Sugar Version 6.5.25 (Build 344)

Tags: php, suitecrm

I have created 2 custom modules, leaveadmin & leaveall and using relate datatype i am populating values in one field.
I am getting the **"name"** values in one field.

> But i need to populate other values in other field when i change the
>   value of relate field.
>   i.e if i change the value in relate field the value in another field should be fetched from the other column values and populate in another field.

Any solution would help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: question, the information that you need to populate the rest of the fields are linked to the chosen 'related field', or are calculated fields?

Comment: its for 'related field'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Maybe there are other solutions,

> **but I used custom JS and made AJAX call to achieve this.**

- If there are any other solutions, i will make a try to those also. Please suggest